# What does the -b argument do in csh?

Tags: linux, shell, csh, tcsh

I am looking at a tcsh script that has the following shebang line:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -fb

# then executes some commands
```

What does the -b do?

From the man page:

> -b  Forces a ''break'' from option processing, causing any further shell  arguments  to
>              be  treated  as  non-option  arguments.  The remaining arguments will not be inter-
>              preted as shell options.  This may be used to pass options to a shell script  with-
>              out  confusion or possible subterfuge.  The shell will not run a set-user ID script
>              without this option.

But I don't really understand what it means...

An example would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say, for example, you have a script that is named `--help` and you want to execute it using `tcsh`:

```
tcsh --help
```

This will obviously not work. The `-b` forces `tcsh` to stop looking for arguments and treat the rest of the command line as file names or arguments to scripts. So, to run the above weirdly named script, you could do

```
tcsh -b --help
```

Comment: Actually in the scenareo used in this answer the shebang line doesn't come into play.  --- if your wierdly named script is executable and invoked simply with "--help",only then the shebang option comes into play and makes it work.  (I am actually surprised that it does..).